# Django and MPTT - get only leaf nodes

Tags: django, django-mptt

I'm new to Django and MPTT and having hard time figuring out how to get all leaf nodes and send them directly to Form class.
For example, I have created MPTT Category Model, and have hierarchy like this:

- Category1
  - Category2
  - Category3

- Category4
  - Category5
  - Category6

So I want only to get leaf categories(cat2,3,5,6).My Form class looks something like this:

```
class UploadForm(forms.Form):
    description = forms.CharField(max_length=50)
    category = mpttform.TreeNodeMultipleChoiceField(queryset=Category.objects.all())
    file = forms.FileField()
```

And with queryset=Category.objects.all() I get exactly the same thing above - all Categories and its children.Is there a way I can get only leaf nodes(children), but leaf nodes from ALL categories, not from specific Category instance ? Thanks.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

not used django mptt in a while, but given that a leaf node may be identified by `right == left + 1`, you should be able to filter for this using an [`F()` expression](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#query-expressions)

Comment: Thanks!The solution is Category.objects.filter(lft=F('rght')-1)

Comment: I thought this was working for me w/ Django 1.4.5 & Django MPTT 0.5.5, but realized it was still returning root nodes. Looks like Category.objects.filter(level__gt=0) is a better way, no?

Answer (score 15):

```
Category.objects.filter(children__isnull=True)
```

Comment: I don't know if this solution has any performance hits, but this is simple and straightforward! To be clear `children` in this case is the `related_name` of whatever you called your parent relationship on the MPTT model.

Answer (score 2):

Unoptimal solution:

```
Category.objects.filter(id__in=[category.id for category in Category.objects.all() if category.is_leaf_node()])
```

Answer (score 0):

My little snippet for django mptt

from django.db import models

```
class CategoryManager(models.Manager):
    def get_leaf(self, level=2):
        return self.filter(level__lte=level).order_by('tree_id','lft').all()

class Category(models.Model):
     objects = CategoryManager()
```

profit, use it: Catalog.objects.get_leaf()

Answer (score 0):

From docs:

```
is_leaf_node()
```

Returns `True` if this model instance is a leaf node (it has no children), `False` otherwise.